# Does psycopg2's "execute()" offer sufficient SQL injection prevention?

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, psycopg2

Can I sleep easy knowing that no SQL Injection can get past pycopg2?

Of course assuming that I correctly use it.  By this I understand that I have to actually use the parameterisation [(sp?)](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2093) feature of the cursor.execute() function, eg

```
my_cur.execute(insert_statement, value_list)
```

And NOT something like

```
my_cur.execute(insert_statement % value_list)
```

The question is whether there is any value in me ALSO parsing and adding escapes to the strings in value_list.

Answer (score 3):

> The question is whether there is any value in me ALSO parsing and adding escapes to the strings in value_list.

No, you should not need to do that.  The entire point of the two-argument form is to *avoid* having to escape strings.  If you escape them manually, psycopg2 will escape them again, so that the escaped form is visible to end users.  This is probably not what you intend.